# res.jwt is not a function - NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I kept getting

```
res.jwt is not a function
```

I have installed `jwt-express` and import it like so

```
import jwt from 'jwt-express'
```

This is my *auth.js*

```
import Account from '../services/account.js'
import env from 'dotenv'
import _ from 'lodash'

const dotenv = env.config();

module.exports = {
    /**
     * Process the user login, generating and returning a token if successful.
     *
     * @return {res}
     */
    async login(req, res, next) {
        try {
            let origin = req.headers.origin;
            let accounts = await Account.getAccounts();

            let account = _.find(accounts, {
                'email_address' : req.body.username,
                'password' : req.body.password
            });

            if (!account) {
                res.send('Username/Password Wrong');
            }

            // res.send(account);

            let authentication = res.jwt({
                'email': account.email_address,
                'id': account.account_id
            });
            res.send(authentication);

        } catch (error) {
            next(error)
        }
    }
};
```

---

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import favicon from 'serve-favicon'
import path from 'path'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import bluebird from 'bluebird'
import jwt from 'jwt-express'
import env from 'dotenv'

//Controllers
import fortinetController from './controllers/fortinet'
import authController from './controllers/auth.js'

//Logger
import logger from './config/logger.js'

//Constant
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const dotenv = env.config();
Promise = bluebird;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(router)
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','favicon.ico')))
app.use(jwt.init('CARWASH', {cookies: false }));


router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the backend provisioning daemon to program FortiManager')
});

router.post('/login', authController.login);

//Fortinet
router.post('/fortinet/login', fortinetController.login);
router.post('/fortinet/getSessionTimeOut', fortinetController.getSessionTimeOut);
router.post('/fortinet/logout', fortinetController.logout);

//Error handling function
app.use((err,req,res,next) => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    res.status(500).send(`Red alert! Red alert!: ${err.stack}`)
    logger.error(`${req.method} ${req.url} - ${err.log || err.message}`);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Your server is running on ${PORT}`)
    }
);
```

How can I debug this?

---

## Update

I've tried to add this

```
console.log(jwt);
```

I got

```
[nodemon] 1.17.3                                                                                        
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`                                                            
[nodemon] watching: *.*                                                                                 
[nodemon] starting `babel-node ./index.js`                                                              
{ active: [Function: active],                                                                           
  clear: [Function: clear],                                                                             
  create: [Function: create],                                                                           
  init: [Function: init],                                                                               
  options:                                                                                              
   { cookie: 'jwt-express',                                                                             
     cookieOptions: { httpOnly: true },                                                                 
     cookies: false,                                                                                    
     refresh: true,                                                                                     
     reqProperty: 'jwt',                                                                                
     revoke: [Function: revoke],                                                                        
     signOptions: {},                                                                                   
     stales: 900000,                                                                                    
     verify: [Function: verify],                                                                        
     verifyOptions: {} },                                                                               
  require: [Function: require],                                                                         
  valid: [Function: valid] }                                                                            
Your server is running on 3000
```

Comment: well have you debugged what is it

Comment: I don't know how.

Comment: then you should be asking that otherwise you're going to run into problems every time you get a outcome you dont expect

Comment: add --inspect in your npm scripts https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: Everything seems fine, app is running, I installed everything, and imported it too. 
I'm stucked.

Comment: just console.log res.jwt what does it say

Comment: I tried that I kept getting `res.jwt is not a function`

Comment: well you havent told me what its logged cba you would still get that error but i want to know the output.  i looked at jwt-express dont see anywhere to usage you're doing good luck

Comment: have you init the middle ware or are you expecting it to jsut be there?

Comment: I have init it like this `app.use(jwt.init('CARWASH', {cookies: false }));`  - let me share the whole `index.js`

Answer (score 2):

1. You are not configuring `express-jwt` correctly.
2. You are using `express-jwt` completely wrong.

Let's walk through each point.

I'm not sure why you think you need to call `jwt.init(...)` when the documentation [here](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) states to simply do: `jwt(...)`. So you'll need to make the following changes:

Change

```
app.use(jwt.init('CARWASH', {cookies: false }));
```

To

```
app.use(jwt({secret: 'CARWASH'}));
```

There does not exist a `cookies` options, not sure where you got that from.

Now `express-jwt` will only handle **verification** of the JWT. It does **not** generate JWT for as you are trying to do in your `auth.js`.

In order to generate JWT, you will need another module: [`jsonwebtoken`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). You will then use the module in your `auth.js` like so:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
// ...

module.export = {
    async login(req, res, next) {
        try {
            // ... auth logic omitted

            // Here we generate the JWT
            // Make sure the JWT secret is the SAME secret you used for express-jwt
            let authentication = jwt.sign({
                'email': account.email_address,
                'id': account.account_id
            }, 'CARWASH');
            res.send(authentication);
        }
        catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So should I remove this line ? `import jwt from 'jwt-express'`

Comment: I got the cookie from this npm package : `jwt-express`

Comment: My mistake, wasn't aware there was another with similar name to `express-jwt`. Anyways, the answer above is for `express-jwt` which will achieve what you want.

Comment: Please provide answer with the package that I was looking to solve not suggested a new one.